# How much memory does an int take on Sun's 64-bit JVM?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I know that Java's implementation does everything it can to hide that information from developers, but I'm building a memory-bound algorithm which does not depend on third-party libraries, so that information would come in handy.

In particular, I am allocating many large `int[]` arrays as instance variables. I will investigate more compact representation soon, but right now I'm interested in knowing how much space is used to a plain array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, an `int` field *could* end up taking up more than 4 bytes due to padding... but fundamentally it's 4 bytes (32 bits). As for whether it *does* take more than 4 bytes, you'd have to experiment to find out. That's reasonably easy to do for fields within an object; harder for stack-based `int` values.

For example, a large array of `int` will always take up roughly 4 times its length (+ a small amount of overhead for the length etc). I don't believe padding will be applied between elements - although it would be relatively easy to verify that. The value returned by `Runtime.totalMemory() - Runtime.freeMemory()` should only be used carefully, but if you allocate an array of 1 million ints in one run, then 2 million ints in another, then 3 million ints next etc it should be reasonably clear what's going on.

Sample code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    long before = getUsedMemory();
    int[] array = new int[size];
    long after = getUsedMemory();

    long difference = after - before;
    System.out.println("Total difference: " + (after - before));
    System.out.println("Per element: " + ((double) difference) / size);
    System.out.println(array); // Make sure the array isn't GC'd early
  }

  private static long getUsedMemory() {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    return rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();
  }
}
```

On my machine, trying this with 100000, 2000000 and 3000000 gives "4*size + 16" bytes for all runs.

Comment: Thank you! I just clarified my question as you suggested :)

Comment: @abahgat: I've edited my question to make it slightly clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Just an `int` by itself?  That probably depends on what it is adjacent to, etc.  Or do you mean an array of `int`?  I'm 99% sure that will take 4-bytes in all reasonable JVM implementations (plus some fixed overhead for the array object itself).

```
long before = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
int foo[] = new int[123456];
System.out.println("Approximate bytes per int: "
  + (before - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/(float)123456);
```

Reports:

Approximate bytes per int: 4.0001945

Comment: I should add that's using a 64-bit JVM, as you wondered about.

Answer (score 0):

[An `int` in Java is always 32 bits.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1)

Comment: Sure, but a compliant implementation could use any number of bits greater than 32 to represent them, as long as it meets the spec.  For example, booleans only  have two states in the spec, but they are certainly represented by more than 1 bit in general.

Comment: This is just a specification, it only guarantees that it will complain somehow or misbehave if you try to put some number inside an `int` which is more that 32 bytes. But inside it could be implemented in any possible way, even by allocating 1 Gb for each int and using only 4 bytes for it. Though it certainly would be ridiculous, it is possible :)